# How do I convert values to iterators

Tags: c++, stl

I think the erase function in vector takes an iterator. But I have a situation where I have the vector values passed on to it, so how do I convert them to an iterator

```
vec.erase(max(*vec.begin(),*vec.end()));
```

Comment: That code is utterly wrong from inception because you're dereferencing `end()`. That said, this certainly seems an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should use the iterator returned from [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)`(vec.begin(), vec.end())`, and that, only if the vector isn't empty.

Comment: It worked thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

Your goal *appears* to be to delete the maximum value in a vector. If so, and assuming that value type is comparable using `operator <`, then you use a combination of `std::vector::erase` along with the `std::max_element` returned iterator.

Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

int main()
{

    // fill a vector of 1..30
    std::vector<int> vec(30);
    std::iota(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);

    // shuffle
    std::mt19937 rng{ std::random_device{}() };
    std::shuffle(vec.begin(), vec.end(), rng);

    // report values
    for (auto x : vec)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout.put('\n');

    // erase an instance of the largest element
    vec.erase(std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end()));

    // report values
    for (auto x : vec)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout.put('\n');
}
```

Sample Output

```
10 4 22 16 15 25 1 28 2 29 13 5 27 14 3 17 19 23 21 11 26 20 8 30 24 6 12 18 9 7 
10 4 22 16 15 25 1 28 2 29 13 5 27 14 3 17 19 23 21 11 26 20 8 24 6 12 18 9 7
```

Note that 30 is missing from the second sequence.